# exslt distinct() does not work with xalan compiled (but works in interpreted)

Tags: xslt, xalan, xsltc

I have this:

```
<xsl:message><xsl:copy-of select="set:distinct(//property)"/> </xsl:message>
<!--<xsl:message><xsl:copy-of select="set:distinct(common:node-set($mss)/indirect)"/> </xsl:message>-->
```

If I uncomment the second line, it does not work<sup>1</sup> when I use the stylesheet with compiled stylesheet in xalan.

It does work when I run xalan from the command line without `-xsltc`.

Am I doing something wrong?

---

<sup>1</sup> I get some cryptic error message, and processing stops. Here is the error message for this instance: `ERROR:  ''`, but I got things like `ERROR: -1` as well.

My `<xsl:stylesheet>` header contains `xmlns:set="http://exslt.org/sets"`.

Comment: Please include your definition of the variable `$mss`. Could you also include some sample XML for testing?